# Get bad WSDL from SoapFault?

Tags: php, soap-client

I'm connecting to a 3rd party service with SoapClient. Most of the time it works fine, but every once in awhile, maybe once out of every 100-150 calls, I get the error

> Soap Failed: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: unexpected  in complexType

My code is in a try/catch with a retry, and it will work on the next round through. But I'd like to examine the WSDL to find out why that fails, partly for my own curiosity, and in case I need to pass it along to the company I'm connecting to. Can I get that information from the SoapFault? Or would I have to call the URL to get the string? I'm afraid if I get the WSDL after the fact, it may already be fixed.

```
$pass = FALSE;
$this->soap = NULL;
$this->session = NULL;
do {
    try {
        Doc::i("Starting session");
        $this->soap = new SoapClient($this->wsdl_url, ['trace' => 1]);
        $pass = TRUE;
    } catch (\SoapFault $e) {
        Doc::e('Soap Failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
        if(str_contains($e->getMessage(),'Parsing Schema') && !empty($e->detail)) {
            Doc::e($e->detail); // Something new I'm trying to see if it helps
        }
    } catch (FatalErrorException $e) {
        Doc::e("Soap failed really bad: " . $e->getMessage());
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Doc::e("Soap failed bad: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
} while (!$pass);
```

Comment: [`__getLastResponse`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php), since you're using `trace`?

Comment: I found `__getLastResponse()`, and just added that in as well. I'm hoping it works next time I get the error. Thanks for backing that up!

Comment: Good luck! These kinds of errors are annoying. I posted an official answer in case that ultimately works out.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`$this->soap->__getLastResponse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php) since you are passing `'trace' => 1` option to `SoapClient`.

You might also consider logging [`$this->soap->__getLastRequest`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php) as well as the headers versions of both of these to ensure you're capturing as much information as possible at run-time.

Refer to the [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) method list for the possible options. Just remember the trick here is the `trace` option: without that, these will not return anything useful!

Comment: I really hoped this would work, but instead i got `Call to a member function __getLastResponse() on a non-object`.

Comment: Hmm, that suggests the `\SoapClient` isn't being created. Please update your OP with the latest code using `__getLastResponse`.

Comment: Walking the PHP engine source, it seems like the [__doRequest](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/soap/soap.c#L2585-L2586) is failing. You *may* be able to gather just-in-time information by creating your own client class and overriding [`__doRequest`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php), like in [this example](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/soap/tests/typemap008.phpt#L9-L14).